# System design for matching closest registered store based on zip code?

Tags: php, mysql

I have the following problem.

I am creating a restaurant delivery system.

So restaurants choose the zipcodes they want to deliver. So in Boston, they might choose Either all of Boston or Back Bay (a specific area of Boston with several zip codes .... ).

Basically, the restaurant confirms the areas they are willing to serve by ticking boxes that are described as follows:

```
- Cambridge (ZIP CODE)
- Boston (all of Boston)
--- Back Bay (covers zip codes: 02...., 02.., 02..)
--- North Boston (covers zip codes: 02145, 021..., 02..., 02..)
```

Users type in their zipcodes, and I match them to the areas that Restaurants specified.

What is the best way to design such a system? I don't think I am going in the right direction...

Comment: best S.O question title ever :-)

Comment: if a restaurant chooses a named area, must they deliver to all contained zips? And, hypothetically, how many named areas can a restaurant select? I think I would use two tables, one that is just two columns: zip and area, and then another where each entry is a restaurant, a few columns for their eligible areas, their lat, lng, etc. Then you could accept the user inputted ZIP, turn it into an area, then query all of the restaurants with that area listed

Comment: People would have downvoted the question based on the title, But the title is funny

Comment: Yes, the title is funny, but it's pretty useless otherwise. Changed it to something more useful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

is this only for Boston or would it be global? Will you be looking at exact zipcode matches? What if someone enters a zipcode you don't have but it's within the delivery range. I would recommend using longitude / latitude lookups.

This might be a good place to start: https://developers.google.com/maps/articles/phpsqlsearch

BTW: I'm looking to do something very similar and will most likely use the article referenced above :)  thanks for helping me too.

Comment: Another reason for doing it with real location (lat, long) is that you can then include restaurants from nearby zips. Also, if they (the customers) specify a location with greater precision, then a restaurant in an adjoining zip might actually be closer to them than one in a remote part of their own zip code area.